# Why would you not scale down pages for digital proofing?

Tags: print-production, scale, prepress, proofing

I read a good book on DTP.

The author stated, that one should not scale down the pages for digital proofing. (To cut costs). Instead he advises, that one should pick the most significant fragments of the pages and proof these.

Unfortunalety the author doesn't explain this further. I would like to ask, why not scale down the pages for digital proofing? What is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One good reason is that scaling down removes details which do not come back if the image is zoomed in. Photos and many other images are bitmaps which can suffer badly. Only vector data can stand it without losses if it's watched on a screen in a vector graphics capable program, but the degradation will be the same also for vectors if it's printed on paper in a "digital printer" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_printing

Try it. Zoom out for ex. this web page in your browser, let the new size be 50%. Take a screenshot. Then watch the result in an image editor in original size (=zoomed in to 200%).

I guess the customer could get nervous if this happened in front of his eyes.